# Typescript Record with dynamic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've got a class that returns a Record. I know all record names and I want to attach types to them. Is there an elegant way of doing so? My code so far looks like this:

```
interface DataInterface {
    bar: number;
    foo: string;
    fooBar: boolean;
}

export class MyClass {
  public bar: number;
  public foo: string;
  public fooBar: boolean;

  constructor(data: Record<string, DataInterface>) {
    this.bar = data.bar; // ERROR: Type 'DataInterface' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    this.foo = data.foo; // ERROR: Type 'DataInterface' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    this.fooBar = data.fooBar; // ERROR: Type 'DataInterface' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  }
}
```

How would you handle it considering I might have a lot of items in `DataInterface`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DataInterface` directly

```ts
  constructor(data: DataInterface) {
    this.bar = data.bar;
    this.foo = data.foo;
    this.fooBar = data.fooBar;
  }
```

Because `DataInterface` is already a Object/Record